# Resetting the selected values in Google visualization category picker control

Tags: javascript, button, google-visualization, reset, dashboard

Here is a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HtWj8/1/) in which there is Google visualization category picker control. I am trying to reset the selected values of category picker as,

```
function dashboardReady() {
      // reset the category picker when clicked.
    document.getElementById('resetButton').onclick = function() {
      categoryPicker.setState({'categoryPicker.getState().selectedValues' : 'none'});
      categoryPicker.draw();
    };
  }
```

using a button `<button style="margin: 2em" id="resetButton">Reset</button>`. 
How to reset it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setState()` to set initial values:

```
    var reset = document.getElementById('resetButton');
    reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
        categoryPicker.setState({selectedValues: ['CPU', 'Memory']});
        categoryPicker.draw();
    }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks.. It is `categoryPicker.setState({selectedValues: []});` for null. Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/HtWj8/2/